# Simple dynamic forms with Flask/Flask-WTF

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-wtforms

I need to build a simple form with a number of checkboxes. The problem is that I need the checkboxes to come from a csv file which would look like this:

data_so.csv

```
Name
A. Blabla
U. Blublu
I. Blibli
O. Bloblo
```

The form, right now, with some hard coded checkboxes, looks like this:

[image]

Instead of "Mr. 1", I'd need to have "A. Blabla", instead of "Ms. 2", I'd want "U. Blublu", etc. and instead of 3 checkboxes, I'd need 4, the number of entries in my csv file.

Here are my Flask files:

route_so.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash
from forms_so import ContactForm
import csv

app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = 'development key'

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
  form = ContactForm()

  if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.validate() == False:
      flash('All fields are required.')
      return render_template('home_so.html', form=form)
    else:
      print(form.node_1.data,form.node_2.data,form.node_3.data)
      return render_template('home_so.html', success=True)

  elif request.method == 'GET':
    return render_template('home_so.html', form=form)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(debug=True)
```

form_so.py

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
import csv
from wtforms import TextField, RadioField, TextAreaField, SubmitField, validators, BooleanField

class ContactForm(Form):

    # my attempt to force the creation of dynamic global variables
    with open('/data_so.csv', 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        r = list(reader)

    nodes = {}
    for i in range(1,len(r)):
        globals()[''.join("node_"+str(i))] = BooleanField(r[i][0])
    # end of my attempt to force the creation of dynamic global variables

    node_1 = BooleanField("Mr. 1")
    node_2 = BooleanField("Ms. 2")  
    node_3 = BooleanField("Dr. 3")
    # this needs to be dynamically set instead

    submit = SubmitField("Send")
```

So I tried and created dynamic variables (in a dirty, hacky way). The problem now is that I don't know how to make the home_so.html work with an undifined number of variables...

home_so.html

```html
{% extends "layout_so.html" %}

{% block content %}

  {% if success %}
    <p>Thank you for filling up our survey. We'll get back to you shortly.</p>

  {% else %}  

    <form action="{{ url_for('home') }}" method=post>
      {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

       <h2>List of check boxes dynamically built from local csv file</h2>

      #this needs to be dynamically set
      {{ form.node_1.label }}
      {{ form.node_1 }}

      {{ form.node_2.label }}
      {{ form.node_2 }}

      {{ form.node_3.label }}
      {{ form.node_3 }}

      {{ form.submit }}
    </form>

  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this sort of things with a simple csv file? If not, what's the usual way to go about dynamically producing a form as it loads client-side?

Answer (score 1):

```
{% for node in node_list_from_app %}
  <p class="field"><label><input type="checkbox" name="node" value="{{ node }}"> {{ node }}</label></p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks! I also need to change the Python code in form_so.py, don't I?

Comment: Of course, but I'm novice and experimenting only with plain Flask, without WTForms, so I'm not sure, how you should change code in app.